# MDX filter on fixed value depending on hierarcy level

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to build a named set with mdx which tells me for a whole year what which are the large records. I cannot share my data, so I'll use a sales example.

All sales reps. need to enter their sales numbers in a application and on top of that database there is a cube configured. One of the goals is to find weird sales behaviour in this cube. This would mean a sales rep that is selling 100k every year, suddenly only sells 30k a year.

I have created a dynamic set that allows me to filter on this by using a calculated member named 'qualifies'. This qualifies is defined like this. (Diff is calculated before)

```
CREATE MEMBER Currentcube.qualifies AS iif(abs([Diff]) > 50000, 1, NULL),DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Check big difference';
```

So this check can be used to filter all the sales reps that have a difference of 50k sales.

When I add aonther filter to my cube, for example region, the 50k threshold will never be exceeded, because no body has more than 50k sales in one region. I want to make the 50K dynamic based on my where clause in my filter.

My question is, is this possible? I'm fairly new to MDX so if this is an easy question, please  forgive me. I have been trying lots of different scenario's but none gave a wanted result. I have been looking online, but this specific scenario hasn't passed in my search results.

Comment: Rather than filter on an absolute difference such as 50k, why not use a percentage difference. In conjunction with the ParallelPeriod function, you should be able to show differences for any query. If you would like further help with writing that MDX let me know.

Comment: Yeah, this is true, I was thinking of changing my example. I also need to filter the big fishes, when someone sells 2000 and the year before only 1000, this data is not interesting because the absolute value is to small

Comment: That's fair enough. You can also write a member that disregards the current query context and only calculates at the aggregated level you require, so will still show you correct results no matter how you filter.

Comment: can you go deeper into that, I don't really see what you are saying

Comment: @jelle Why not combine the approach, and use something like "percentage difference > 10% and absolute difference > 10000" as the filter condition?

Comment: because, when I filter on region, 10000 does not make any sense anymore, because no one would have such sales in a single region

Comment: @jelle you write a calculation that ignores any other filter conditions in your query and just shows whether sales have gone uo by 50k since last year, ignoring other conditions such as region. Is that clearer?